# SwiftUI Button touch area is abnormal

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I created SwiftUI Button and its touch area is slightly strange. The touch area extends the label of the button.

This is my code.

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
        
            Button {
                print("aaaaaa")
            } label: {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                .background(Color.yellow)
            }
        
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(height: 50.0)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

And I'll attach the result in simulator.

The button area is filled with yellow color. But I could click the button outside of yellow color.

The same thing happens in real device too.

How is this possible?

[image: Touch area]

Comment: Yes it is expected with the button in `SwiftUI`. In case if you want to limit the touch area to visible area of button, you can use `Button {print("ButtonTapped")} label: {Text("Button")}.contentShape(Rectangle())`

Comment: iOS has always been this way, because fingers are inaccurate pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a completely normal behavior of `Button`/`onTapGesture` in `SwiftUI`. Its touch area is slightly bigger than its **border size**.

This is not a bug or glitch.

Comment: Sure, but is there a way to disable this behavior?